# How do I convert numeric survey responses to binary 1,0?

Tags: r

I've been trying to recode the survey data so that the response options range from 0-4. Currently, the response range from -1 to 9.
I've tried `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(rp == < 4, 1,0)
```

but I still get `-1` and `0` responses.

I've tried:

```
rp <- ifelse(-1== 0 |0 == 0 | 1== 1 | 2 == 1 | 3==1 | 4 == 1 |9 ==0, 1,0)
```

This returns `1`s only.

Comment: Your first attempt is close, but you didn't do the comparison right - `ifelse(rp < 4, 1, 0)`. You only need one of `==` (equals),  `<` (less than), `>` (greater than) etc.

Comment: As thelatemail says, your first attempt needs a minor fix. The issue with your second attempt is that is doesn't use the existing variable. `-1 == 0` is false, because `-1` is not equal to `0`. `0 == 0` is true, `0` is always equal to `0`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first try note that `== <` is not a proper comparison.
For the second approach, notice how you are comparing integers with each other? You are comparing `-1 == 0` and `0 == 0`, etc…
Since one of them is true (`0 == 0`) and you are using a logical `or`, it will always return 1.

To solve your problem, think about how you could use multiple if-statements. Maybe this pseudocode will help:

```
if in between two numbers then
     set response to 0
else if in between two numbers then
     set response to 1
and so on…
```